# Cannot find fully qualified class: org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am making a web project using `Bootsfaces` v1.1.1 and `JSF` components on Eclipse. After not being able to use the components like panels and accordions fully as they are shown on the website, I did decide to check if I was missing anything on setup process. So I found out that I should also have added the following piece of code as it is mentioned as following on Bootsfaces' website:

> adding the CombinedResourceHandler of OmniFaces to the
>   faces-config.xml should fix nasty resource loading problems:

So I did add the following code to my `faces - config.xml` file :

```
<application>
       <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
   </application>
```

Now I get the following warning and my project doesn't deploy at all.

> Cannot find fully qualified class:
>   org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler

If I force to run, I get

> cannot Deploy MyProject deploy is failing=Application with name
>   [MyProject] is not deployed

error.

So I would like to ask:

- Do I have to update my `faces - config.xml` file at all in order to use bootsfaces component properly?(Because my
  xhtml files were at least running before updating.)
- How can I solve this error and properly update my `faces - config.xml`
  file?

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have solved the issue by deleting the Glassfish Server and setting it back. Now, even components like panels that weren't working before are working well. But I also removed the code that I added into `faces-config.xml` that I mentioned above. Apparently, I don't have to update my `faces-config.xml` file, updating `web.xml` is enough I guess.

Comment: Please add this as an answer and accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you @JasperdeVries for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by deleting the `Glassfish Server` and setting it back. Now, even components like panels that weren't working before are working well. But I also removed the code that I added into `faces-config.xml` that I mentioned above. Apparently, I don't have to update my `faces-config.xml` file, updating `web.xml` is enough I guess.